# Anylogic: assemble multiple agents at once in assmbler block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Is it possible to assemble multiple agents at once in an "assembler" block. I mean that if an agent is composed of two types of parts, and there are three parts of each type, and we have enough resources (e.g. 3 workers) is it possible to assemble these three products simultaneously. in my model they are assembled one by one and there is no option like queue capacity which does the same in "service" block.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assembler** always works one-at-a-time. To have this work in parallel, the model would need to contain 3 separate assemblers with some sort of routing logic to ensure that parts are spread across the assemblers and don't all end up in one block to be processed serially.